# store complex object in db using dapper

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, orm, dapper

So I'm trying to store a record in the databse using dapper. I'm passing an object to the method where I have my query to store the recorde. Let me be more clear. Below is my model :

```
public class Foo
{
 public long FooId { get; set; }
 public Guid Foo2ID { get; set; }
 public string Status { get; set; }
 public Person Person { get; set; } = new Person();
}

public class Person
{
  public string Type { get; set; }
  public string Character { get; set; }
  public DateTime Test { get; set; }
}
```

And this is my query :

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Create(Foo f)
    {
        using (var connection = _dbAccess.CreateConnection())
        {
            var sqlStatement = @"
            INSERT INTO ReportRequests 
              (FooId
              ,Foo2Id
              ,Person
              ,Status)
                VALUES 
                    (@FooId
                    @,Foo2Id
                    @,Person
                    @,Status)";
            await connection.ExecuteAsync(sqlStatement, f);

        };

        return Ok();
    }
```

I'm trying to save a json in the ***Person*** column in the database. But I get this error :

> The member ***x*** of type ***x*** cannot be used as a parameter value

Can anyone please give me an idea on how I can approach to this problem. It would be very helpful.

Thank you a lot **:)**

Answer (score 0):

`enter code here`First of all, you should consider whether you can use LINQ-like queries with dapper. It makes it both more readable and avoids having issues like that.

Back to your problem, from the code you posted it looks like you've misplaced the comas after the @ symbol  `@,Foo2Id` :

```
                    (@FooId
                    @,Foo2Id
                    @,Person
                    @,Status)
```

It should be:

```
                   (@FooId
                    @Foo2Id,
                    @Person,
                    @Status)
```

Comment: It was just a typo when creating my question. In my code `(@FooId
                    @Foo2Id,
                    @Person,
                    @Status)` everything is written corretly. Back to my problem. How can I store a json in a column with dapper? Any Idea?

Comment: You can try JsonConvert.Serialize(object).ToString() but then you will have to sanitize it to avoid parsing errors.